# How to compress the image without loosing quality of the image

Tags: java, android

I have implemented document scanning by camscanner sdk. While taking pictures with  high pixel cameras will consume more MB of each picture. Even after editing with  camscanner sdk, sometimes it exceeds a MB. So this reason i tried whats app compression algorithm to compress the image but its totally decreases the quality. Now, i want to know is there any other possibilities or ideas to compress the picture with in certain KB's. So that the devices which has slow data connection can easy to upload images to server... So now the camscanner sdk doing perfectly but only thing need to decrease the size of an image else required any other idea..

Comment: You should specify what you have explored up till now?

Comment: Simple Google search brings up this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864706/ocr-library-for-android

Answer (score 1):

Please do some search and find out. If you use NDK, better to proceed with tessarat

> http://kurup87.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-ocr-tutorial-image-to-text.html

Or simple OCR by using api given. Hope this might help

https://github.com/smart-mobile-software/ocrapiservice

Comment: Hi.. I do know this about OCR. I'm not extracting the texts from images.. I just want to scan the images with more clearence like camscanner.. but only thing is i am not able to decrease the size of an image.. suppose, if i try to decrease, quality goes down.. please read the question..